# Replacing display page with views in template.php

Tags: views, theming

since yesterday I can not solve the problem with function preprocess_views_view:
In the views named 'Calendar' I have a few display page(page_classic, page_mobile) and I would like to change preprocess_views_view function in mobile version of the site, which replace default display page(page_classic) with page_mobile. Below function, does not work:(

```
function mobiletheme_preprocess_views_view(&$vars){
    dpm($vars);
    $view = views_get_view('calendar');
    if($view->name=='calendar'){
        $display_id = 'page_mobile';
        $view->current_display = $display_id;
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Views' hooks are called whenever a View is called, yet you are calling the creation of the View once again inside of it, and then trying to change *that* View, not the original one.

Instead, you should be doing something along the lines of...

```
function mobiletheme_preprocess_views_view(&$vars) {

  $name=$vars['name'];
  $display_id=$vars['display_id'];

  switch ($name) {

     case 'calendar':

       // process it here, eg change/add $vars['foo']
       break;

     // other Views here

  }

}
```

Now, that, changing template variables, doesn't appear to be what you want to be doing, so you will have to look into some of the other Views hooks, most probably views_pre_view to change the display, eg, something like...

```
function mobiletheme_views_pre_view(&$view, &$display_id, &$args) {

  if ($view->name=='calendar' && display_id=='page_classic') {
    $view->set_display('page_mobile');
  }

}
```

Addition/Caveat:  This appears to have to be called from a module, not a theme (at least in D6), so you may need something like this...

```
function mobilemodule_views_pre_view(&$view, &$display_id, &$args) {
  global $theme;

  if ($theme=='mobiletheme' && $view->name=='calendar' && display_id=='page_classic') {
    $view->set_display('page_mobile');
  }

}
```

...inside a small module.